# How to access a private data members of base class in the derived class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Since we can access the private data member of base class in the derived class with the help of friend function. How can we do the same in C# asp.net? I mean whats the alternative of friend function in C# asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`internal` is the access modifier for stuff that needs tobe accessible in a single assembly. `protected` is the modifier to get access to base class stuff.

If you have no control over the base class and need to 'hack' access, [NHibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/) does that sort of thing, e.g. when creating a performant setter on private instance fields. In this case the source code of the method `NHibernate.Bytecode.Lightweight.ReflectionOptimizer.GenerateSetPropertyValuesMethod` could be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection... this might give you a start...

[How do I use reflection to invoke a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method-in-c)