# Retrieve private methods of a class using reflection

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, reflection, copy

I want to retrieve the private (implementation and other) methods of a class which implements an interface and also is derived from (inherits) a base class.

1. How can I achieve this using reflection?
2. Is there another way to achieve this?

This is what I'm trying to do. I need to view these private methods and their contents. I don't want to invoke them.

```
Dim assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly 
Dim assemblyName As String assemblyName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("xyz.dll") 
assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyName) 

assembly.GetType("myClass").Getmethods(Bindings.NonPublic)
```

`assembly.GetType("myClass").GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic)` isn't working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to invoke a private method in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method-in-c)

Comment: see the updated question, this is not a duplicate

Comment: is it you own assembly or an external assembly? Is sufficient trust established between the two assemblies?

Answer (score 3):

Making the assumption that you're trying to use the private methods of a 3rd party assembly:

I'd urge caution in using private methods, they have been made private for a reason and 
might rely on some state that you won't be able to anticipate; Also, if the assembly gets updated in the future, the private behavior may be changed or removed causing you to have to re-write your code to compensate.

However, there are two methods at your disposal, if you want to continue.
One way us using the new Dynamic keyword in .net 4:

http://igoro.com/archive/use-c-dynamic-typing-to-conveniently-access-internals-of-an-object/

To use reflection, this question may help you:

[How do I use reflection to invoke a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method-in-c)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

BindingFlags

You must specify **Instance** or **Static** along with Public or NonPublic or no members will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assembly myAssembly;
myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\xyz.dll");                       
Type myType = myAssembly.GetTypes()[0]; //change 0 according to your class type.
BindingFlags eFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("Methodname", eFlags);                   
object obj1 = myAssembly.CreateInstance(myType.FullName);
object obj2 = myMethod.Invoke(obj1, new object[2] { parameters1, parameters1  });
```