# Is there a way to call private functions of a form or class through Type.InvokeMember or messages in C#?

Tags: c#, messaging, invoke, private-methods

What I have is a bunch of forms in my main application that have both private and public functions. I have a plugin architecture in place that accesses each form when it is created and loaded and holds a reference to it for updating it, adding controls, etc.

What we are trying to do is implement this plug in architecture, but some plugins may need to call a form's private functions. Here is an example of what I tried with Type.InvokeMember:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SayHello()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

In another DLL...

```
public class PluginClass
{
    Form1 myReferencedForm1;

    PluginClass()
    {
        //Constructor code here...

        //Also sets the reference to existing Form1 instance
    }

    private CallMember()
    {
        Type t = typeof(Form1); //I guess I can also call 'myReferencedForm1.GetType();' here as well
        t.InvokeMember("SayHello",
                       System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
                       System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                       System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public,
                       null, myReferencedForm1, new object[] { });
    }
}
```

I have tried `"SayHello"` and `"SayHello()"` and they both return a 'MissingMethodException' error:

```
Method 'Form1.SayHello()' not found.
```

Do I need to create and use a Binder? If so how do I do that? Can I do this easier with a System.Windows.Forms.Message? If so how?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How do I use reflection to invoke a private method in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method-in-c)

Comment: Are these in the same dll? You could make SayHello() internal rather than private if so

Comment: No, they are not. I will update the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included `BindingFlags.Instance` in your list of flags... so it doesn't have either instance or static methods to check!

Personally I usually call `GetMethod` and then `MethodInfo.Invoke` to separate the discovery of the method from the invocation. I find that makes it easier to debug, but YMMV.

Complete sample:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class OtherClass
{
    private void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OtherClass.Foo");
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        OtherClass target = new OtherClass();
        typeof(OtherClass).InvokeMember("Foo",
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null, target, new object[0]);
    }
}
```

Or using my "separate fetch from invocation":

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class OtherClass
{
    private void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OtherClass.Foo");
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        OtherClass target = new OtherClass();
        MethodInfo method = typeof(OtherClass).GetMethod("Foo",
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // Could now check for method being null etc
        method.Invoke(target, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I should know better... I can't beat Jon Skeet to one of these!

Answer (score 2):

Don't try that.

Create a interface: `IPluginHost` with `DoMethod(string Name)` member. Implement that interface for each form, you can even extract it to the other file using `partial class` declaration.

In the method impl, do simple switch case to kick proper method. Use some script to generate it.

```
public interface IPluginHost
{
    void DoMethod(string MethodName);
}

public partial MyForm:Form, IPluginHost
{
    #region IPluginHost implementation
    public void DoMethod(string MethodName)
    {
         switch (MethodName)
             case "SayHello":
                 SayHello();
                 break;
             ...
    }
    #endregion
}
```

If you are doing the *architecture* - don't HACK IT right at the start.

Comment: +1 I have to agree, why go the hard/dirty way when there's a much easier/cleaner way like this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `BindingFlags.Instance` to the list of flags:

```
t.InvokeMember("SayHello", 
               BindingFlags.Intance |
                   BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
                   BindingFlags.NonPublic,
               null, 
               myReferencedForm1,
               new object[] { });
```

But, to be honest, I prefer getting the method and then using the MethodInfo object returned to call the method:

```
if(myReferencedForm1 != null)
{
    var type = typeof(Form1);
    var method = type.GetMethod("SayHello", BindingFlags.Instance
        | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    method.Invoke(myReferencedForm1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `invokeAttr` parameter should be

```
BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your BindingFlags to

```
private CallMember()
{
    Type t = typeof(Form1); //I guess I can also call 'myReferencedForm1.GetType();
    t.InvokeMember("SayHello",
                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                   null, myReferencedForm1, new object[] { });
}
```

This should do the trick.