# .NET Reflector - Reflexil, Change private to public

Tags: reflector, private-members, public-members, reflexil

I have an assembly loaded into .NET reflector and I have the reflexil addin.
I found a method in the assembly but it's private. Copying the whole method to my code is too much work because it uses many other methods in the assembly. I just want to change

private void Check(string Proxy, int Port)

to

public void Check(string Proxy, int Port)

So I can use it in my code. Does anybody know how to change it and how to save the fixed assembly after that?

Kirk

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-writing the assembly, consider using Reflection from your code to invoke the private method dynamically, see:

[How do I use reflection to invoke a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method-in-c)

Comment: @Bart Agreed, it's a bit yucky. I would definitely recommend pairing it with a unit test to make sure there are no regressions if the 3rd party library is updated.