# How to execute a private static method with optional parameters via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, optional-parameters

I have a class with a private static method with an optional parameter.  How do I invoke it from another class via Reflection?  There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method-in-c), but it does not address static method or optional parameters.

```
public class Foo {
    private static void Bar(string key = "") {
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

How do I invoke `Foo.Bar("test")` and `Foo.Bar()` (e.g. without passing the optional parameter)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Optional parameter values in C# are compiled by injection those values at the callsite. I.e. even though your code is

```
Foo.Bar()
```

The compiler actually generates a call like

```
Foo.Bar("")
```

When finding the method you need to treat the optional parameters as regular parameters.

```
var method = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Bar", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

If you know exactly what values you want to invoke the method with you can do:

```
method.Invoke(obj: null, parameters: new object[] { "Test" });
```

If you only have some of the parameters and want to honor the values of the default ones you have to inspect the method's [`ParameterInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.aspx) objects to see if the parameters are optional and what those values are. For example to print out the default values of those parameters you could use the following code:

```
foreach (ParameterInfo pi in method.GetParameters())
{
    if (pi.IsOptional)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pi.Name + ": " + pi.DefaultValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the static method part?

Answer (score 2):

Using this class

```
  public class Foo
  {
    private static void Bar(string key = "undefined key", string value = "undefined value")
    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The key is '{0}'", key));
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The value is '{0}'", value));
    }
  }
```

You can use the following code to call it with the default values

```
  MethodInfo mi = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Bar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
  ParameterInfo[] pis = mi.GetParameters();

  object[] parameters = new object[pis.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < pis.Length; i++)
  {
    if (pis[i].IsOptional)
    {
      parameters[i] = pis[i].DefaultValue;
    }
  }

  mi.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

If the method had some non-optional parameters, you will have to insert them into the parameters array before invoking the method.

E.g

```
private static void Bar(int number, string key = "undefined key", string value = "undefined")
```

Would require you to do

```
parameters[0] = "23"
```

Before invoking

Answer (score 1):

Something i wrote for my unit tests:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to execute a function and provide the result value against the provided source object even if it is private and/or static. Just make sure to provide the correct BindingFlags to correctly identify the function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TReturn">The expected return type of the private method.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="type">The object's Type that contains the private method.</param>
    /// <param name="source">The object that contains the function to invoke. If looking for a static function, you can provide "null".</param>
    /// <param name="methodName">The name of the private method to run.</param>
    /// <param name="flags">Binding flags used to search for the function. Example: (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static) finds a private static method.</param>
    /// <param name="output">The invoked function's return value.</param>
    /// <param name="methodArgs">The arguments to pass into the private method.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true if function was found and invoked. False if function was not found.</returns>
    private static bool TryInvokeMethod<TReturn>(Type type, object source, string methodName, BindingFlags flags, out TReturn output, params object[] methodArgs)
    {
        var method = type.GetMethod(methodName, flags);
        if(method != null)
        {
            output = (TReturn)method.Invoke(source, methodArgs);
            return true;
        }

        // Perform some recursion to walk the inheritance. 
        if(type.BaseType != null)
        {
            return TryInvokeMethod(type.BaseType, source, methodName, flags, out output, methodArgs);
        }

        output = default(TReturn);
        return false;
    }
```

Then call it like so to invoke a private static function:

```
var success = TryInvokeMethod(typeof(Foo), null, "MyPrivateStaticFunc", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, out result, arg1ToPass);
```

Disclaimer: I use this for functions with a return value only. Attempting to execute a method with no return value will throw an exception.