# Using DLL .NET internal method

Tags: .net, windows, reverse-engineering

Is it possible, to use one DLL's internal method ?
I've decompiled the .net dll, using Reflector and dotPeek, and found what I need, name and parameters of the method.
I've already made a simple program to call the public ones, so I'm fine with this.
CFF Explorer ([here](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php)) allows to change some things to public/private/static/etc...
Did anyone tried this with success? Thanks.

Comment: You can do it using Reflection.

See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method-in-c) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use `Reflection`. Consider the following class:

```
public class A
{
    internal void Method(string val) { }
}
```

to consume that method you would need to do something like this:

```
var a = new A();
var methodInfo = a.GetType().GetMethod("Method", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if (methodInfo == null) { return; }  // the method wasn't found on the type

methodInfo.Invoke(a, new object[] { "parameter value" });
```

and if the method returned a value:

```
var result = methodInfo.Invoke(a, new object[] { "parameter value" });
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try it on. .Net is not my language of choice :) :) Thanks

Comment: Michael, what if the class is also private?!?!?