# C# Reflection invoke method in a new process

Tags: c#

I have a WPF application that acts like some kind of 'loader' and with that loader I get a `byte[]` from my SQL server and I invoke that method like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(bin);
MethodInfo method = assembly.EntryPoint;
method.Invoke(null, null);
```

How ever, that will start the new process inside the loader process but when the application been loaded I would like to close the loader. Can I somehow invoke my method as a new procees / inside another process?

Comment: Could you spool the data to disk and start a new process based on that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to invoke a private method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method)

Comment: @DavidPine How is this a duplicate, I don't want to invite a private method, I want to invoke a method so it runs in a new process so I can close my loader process.

Comment: @DavidPine I guess I could, but the reason I want to do it like this is so that the user can't get the hands on the .exe / .dll to easy.

Comment: I have an answer for that then...

Comment: Why do you need to exit the loader process?

Comment: Because the loader is a WPF application and my other application is a Console application. The WPF application takes a lot of RAM, an as the loader is not needed on the Console Application been launcher I see no reason to keep the Loader Active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for handling [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) event. Then you can embedded the primary executable's references as resources, i.e.; the `*.dll's` that your app relies on can be embedded resources. Then when you handle this event, you can get the resource and load the assembly returning it from said event handler.

This is extremely helpful in preventing users from getting there hands on external `.exe / .dll`.

Comment: Ah, yes it did. Just been a tad bit busy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to posses the name/path of the application to run use `Process.Start` method. Details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm not as the .exe is located on a SQL database.

Comment: Can you save it to local file system and then use Process.Start?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reach into another process that way without that process cooperating. Probably, you need to author a managed `exe` that loads the DLL and runs it.

You could even do that in your existing application. Create a command line argument that causes your application to load a DLL and run it instead of showing a WPF UI. Then, restart "yourself".

Or, just close the WPF window and exit the UI thread. That should clean up most of the resources.