# Accessing Private method of other form

Tags: c#, winforms, access-modifiers

How to access private methods from one form to another form?

For Example I have this method in Form1:

Form1:

```
private void Test (){}
```

Then how to access that method (private void Test) in Form2 so that that values that I entered in Form2 will be sent in the method Test??

Test is a datagridview and in form 2 I have to enter Name with corresponding values in it and if I press the save button, it should be automatically save in the datagridview which in in Form1.

Comment: So it should be public void Test () {}??Then what should be the code in Form2 then??

Comment: No you can't access `private` things outside of that class

Comment: First of all: Give good names. If you continue your program with `Form1` and `Form2` you'll have a big problem later, when you didn't touched you code for a while.

Comment: @James, you can use reflection to access private method

Comment: Linked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method (as duplicate) shows how to do exactly what you are asking. Please note that in most cases there are much better approaches to each concrete case - unfortunately it is not possible to suggest as you've not provided reasons why it is private and your ultimate goal.

Comment: [How do you unit test private methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/250692/18192) is a similarly helpful duplicate, but is more directly relevant to the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`private` method is not meant to be accessed outside of its `class` *at all*. You *cannot* access `private` method if you are not in the `class`.

The simplest way for your case would be to make the `private` method `public`

```
public void Test (){}
```

Alternatively, you have to make a `public` wrapper method to call your `private` method:

```
public void TestWrapper() {
    Test(); //if test is private
}
```

And then in your `Form2`, you should have the `instance` of `Form1` and call the method easily like this:

```
//All these are inside Form2
Form1 form1 = new Form1();

//Somewhere in your code
form1.Test(); //if test is public, or
form1.TestWrapper(); //if test is private
```

But in all cases, the bottom line is:

> You cannot call `private` method outside of the `class`.

Comment: you can use reflection to invoke private methods

Comment: @Anand ah yes... that is also a "wrapper" so to speak...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the method of other form then it can not be `private`. You need to make them as `public` to access the method of other form.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access private method from another class.
make it public then you can access it through another class.