# Using Variable as a class name reference

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an interesting question today.
I have a table that stores a void name and from what class file it came from.

Is it possible to read the table and assign a var object based off the data in a variable?

If it is , it would save a ton of coding.

```
public void CallMyFunction()
{
    try
    {
        var checkerList = conn.QueryAsync<FunctionList>("SELECT * FROM FunctionList",null );
        using (IEnumerator<FunctionList> enumer = checkerList.Result.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumer.MoveNext())
            {
                FunctionList current = enumer.Current;
                string myFunctionToCall = current.FunctionName ;
                string myObjectToCall = current.FunctionObject;

                MethodInfo dynMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod(myFunctionToCall,
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                dynMethod.Invoke(myObserverToCall, new object[] { myFunctionToCall });
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `System.Reflection`, you can search for a method reference by name and invoke it with some arguments, yes. Look at (http://stackoverflow.com/a/135482/5296568, http://www.dotnetperls.com/getmethod).

Comment: Is the edit to the code on the correct path  to what you ment ?

Comment: On the correct path, yes.Doesn't compile ofcourse because of the usage of non-defined variables `myObserverToCall`. You should read into Reflection if you want to do this stuff. Basically, it's a technique sothat you can dynamically search for methods in objects or classes (e.g. by name) and call them with some arguments.

Comment: Odd, it compiled fine, It accepted them as strings(the 2 lines up) .. ok will have a look, this will help so much when working

Comment: yeah I can't get this right ..