# what are the conditions and results of (non)completion of Decoder.Convert

Tags: c#, .net, standard-library, decoder

the .net Standard library contains a class `Decoder` with a method `Convert`.

This method decodes the binary data in the input array to character data in the output array. It has an output parameter `completed` to indicate if all bytes passed in were used.

This method is documented to throw an `ArgumentException` if

> The output buffer is too small to contain any of the converted input.

So far, so good, if there is not enough space in the output buffer, `completed` is false, if the output buffer has no available space at all, it throws an `ArgumentException`.

However, the exceptions documentation goes on to say

> The output buffer should be greater than or equal to the size indicated by the `GetCharCount` method.

which has me confused. If the output buffer should be greater or equal to size of the GetCharCount method, shouldn't the `completed` output parameter always be true? If so, what's it use. How is (non)completion signalled exactly?

Comment: Probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49519637/11683

Comment: @GSerg that sure looks relevant, thanks for the pointer.