# How to click a pin programmatically?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maps

I got a map with a list of pins and I'd like to highlight one of them programatically, simulating a click on it.

```
public MapViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IApiAutostradeManagerFactory apiAutostradeFactory) : base(navigationService, apiAutostradeFactory)
{
   Map = new Map
  {
    MapType = MapType.Street,
  };
  Map.PinClicked += Map_PinClicked;
}

private void Map_PinClicked(object sender, PinClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I clicked it!");
    }
}
```

This event is raised correctly everytime i click on a pin, but i'd like to raise it directly from code.
I'm using this this Map Library:
https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution: `Map` contains the property `SelectedPin`. It is enough find the desired pin and set `SelectedPin`. To simulate camera moving after a click, It's necessary use the following method:
`Map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(selectedPin.Position, Distance.FromKilometers(15)));`

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you gave, there's a method called **SendPinClicked** which do what you want but is internal. It takes a pin as a parameter.

You can call it even if it's internal with reflection (as you can find here : [How do I use reflection to invoke a private method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135482/6903009))

So you could probably create an extension method like this (Didn't tested, can't right now) :

```
static class MapExtensions
{
    public static void callPinClicked(this Map m, Pin p)
    {
        var mi = m.GetType().GetMethod(SendPinClicked, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic  | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance );
        if (mi != null) {
            mi.Invoke (m, new object[] { p } );
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could do

```
Map.callPinClicked(_pin);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i called the callPinClicked but nothing happens. I explored more source code, and i find that there is a class called `PinLogic` that contains `OnMakerClick`method that use `SendPinClicked` method, but I'm a bit confused about how them work togheter. Any hint?

Comment: Could you try to debug and see if mi != null on the code I gave ?

Comment: I noticed that event is triggered, because when i call the method `callPinClicked`, the method `Map_PinClicked` is fired and print in console the string. The problem is that pin is not selected on map.

Comment: Well you ask about how to invoke the event that what we did :P Great you found your solution :)