# How to call Private method another class in C#

Tags: c#

I have Two class one is Employee another one is Program.
In Program class it have Private method ViewEmployee()
I need to call private method into another class??

Comment: Why `private` when you want to call it from outside the class? - but here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method

Comment: private methods are not accessible outside the class .

Comment: The fact you want to call a private method leads me to suspect you have an XY problem....methods are private for a reason!

Comment: This is all your own code? Why not just make that method public? Do you have an access modifier at all (private)? If not, just add it `public void ViewEmployee`

Answer (score 2):

You don't. The point of making it private is so your compiler can notify you that you *cannot* call it from another class.

If you want to call it from the same assembly, make it `internal`. If you want to call it from a different assembly, make it `public`.

Answer (score 1):

Private methods are not accessible outside the class. See access modifiers in MSDN
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

If you want to call it from another class in the same namespace then make it

> internal

else if you want to call if from anywhere make it

> public

.